# ExtJS: How to position SplitButton menu relative to SplitButton

Tags: extjs

I have a SplitButton at the bottom of the page and is not visible initially(we need to scroll down to see the bottom). When I scroll to SplitButton, then press arrow button to expand splitbutton's menu, menu appears **under** SplitButton(just as planned),  and then scroll up, **the menu remains on screen**, and it is **positioned relative to window**, not the containing div.
I tried to initialize menu by passing ***floating: false*** to it's config, but in this case menu doesn't expands at all. 
How can I posision SplitButton's menu to have it **always** under SplitButton?

My ExtJS version is 4.07

Comment: Even i am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing something wrong. I've tried with:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    html: 'loooooong panel',
    height: 1500,
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'splitbutton',
            text: 'My button',
            menu: [{
                text: 'Menu1'
            },{
                text: 'Menu2'
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

Live example [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eldono/48jKD/1/), everything works fine. If you still have problems you should modify menuAlign property to suit your needs:

```
 menu: [{
      text: 'Menu1'
 },{
      text: 'Menu2'
 }],
 menuAlign: 'tl-bl?' // Default
```

where 'tl-bl?' means top left corner (of the menu) should be aligned with bottom left corner (of the button) and the '?' means that if there's no space the menu should be automatically moved.